# NodeJS: ENOENT error on calling a shell script

Tags: node.js, enoent

Below is the error I am receiving when attempting to run a shell script located at `/var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh`.

```
exec error: { Error: spawn sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh',
  path: 'sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh',
  spawnargs: [],
  cmd: 'sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh' }
```

The path is from root (/) on purpose.  If I execute this `sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh` while not running NodeJS, it works.  But NodeJS cannot seem to run it.

Most answers I've found say that it is because of an incorrect file path, or because they are calling a relative path as if it is a root path.  But I am calling a root path purposely, and the path is the correct root path.  I cannot find any other answers for this.

**Code**

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var restartScript = exec('sh /var/www/nodejs/restart-server.sh',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error:', error);
        }
    });
```

**Problem Found**

I forgot to change `.execFile` to just `.exec`

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @RenatoGama Sure, it's been added.

Comment: @RenatoGama Of course, as soon as I added it, I realized I forgot to change the `execFile` part...

Comment: Thats right. that seems to be the problem

Comment: @RenatoGama Yes, I am no longer getting that error.  Now it is just not doing anything I expect it to do.  But I will deal with that separately.

Comment: Ok.. update your question if you keep having problems

Comment: @James Can you please answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to change `.execFile` to just `.exec`